# Bigquery customer count

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-search-console

I have to find how many customers have >10 transactions with us, excluding returns?

```
SELECT COUNT(a.CUSTOMER_ID) AS CUSTOMER_COUNT
FROM `sql-project-346814.statfinity_sql_case.customer_table` a 
WHERE a.CUSTOMER_ID IN 
(
  SELECT b.CUST_ID
  FROM `sql-project-346814.statfinity_sql_case.transaction_table` b
  LEFT JOIN `sql-project-346814.statfinity_sql_case.customer_table` ON a.CUSTOMER_ID = b.CUST_ID
  WHERE b.TOTAL_AMT NOT LIKE '-%'
  GROUP BY
    b.CUST_ID
  HAVING 
    COUNT(b.TRANSACTION_ID) > 10
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Selecting customers having positive **total Amounts** and having > 10 transactions.

```
SELECT count(b.CUST_ID) AS CUSTOMER_COUNT
FROM `sql-project-346814.statfinity_sql_case.transaction_table` b
LEFT JOIN `sql-project-346814.statfinity_sql_case.customer_table` ON a.CUSTOMER_ID = b.CUST_ID
WHERE b.TOTAL_AMT > 0
GROUP BY
b.CUST_ID
HAVING 
COUNT(b.TRANSACTION_ID) > 10
```